# Decrypt error with CER file

Tags: windows, encryption, openssl

How can I decrypt a Base64 encoded and encrypted string given the public certificate for that encryption?

I have been reading about OpenSSL but I can get a way to decrypt the string from the .CER file. I'm trying to do it throw Windows command line, but any solutions is appreciated.

Comment: In PKI the encryption is done by the public key and decryption by the corresponding private key. Could you please clarify what do you have to decrypt the string?

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*